# Serializing super/subclasses in Android

Tags: java, android, inheritance, serialization, package

I'm having trouble serializing a abstract superclass in Android, the superclass is in a different package than the subclass (I have several apps that inherit from a core project).

After a lot of searching not finding any real answers I have to ask is this even possible? Do I have to reference the superclass somwhere in the subclass package? All I found is that it inits with the empty constructor which isn't really helpful in this case.

It kinda defeats the purpose if I have to add the superclass to every project...

Hope you understand what I mean, it's been a long time since I did anything remotely complicated in Java before this project.

EDIT:
I have to temporarily store the objects on the device (for up to a couple of days) before they are transfered to a web service, so in my understanding Parcelable is not usable.

Some basic code to try to clarify a bit:

In my core package:

```
package com.test.core;
public abstract class ClassBase implements Serializable {

    public List<Measurments> measurments; // never gets serialized by the subclass.

}
```

In my app package that references the core package:

```
package com.test.app1;
public class ClassName extends ClassBase implements Serializable
```

Comment: Maybe you can post some code to make your set-up more clear to others? Also, you should ideally use Parcelable in Android instead.

Comment: I didn't make it clear in the post, but I need to store the objects on the device for a while before they are synced to a web service, and as I understand it Parcelable doesn't do that.

Comment: As far as i know, Parcelable == Serializable but simply optimized for Android. Why don't you simply store your objects/data into the SQLite database?

Comment: A quick search gave me this "For reasons that will become apparent when we revisit Parcelable objects in Classes That Support Serialization, they cannot be used to store objects beyond the lifetime of an application. They are not an appropriate choice for marshaling state to, say, a database or a file." 

<https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-android-mednieks-1st/chapter-6/serialization> 

The objects are quite complicated and would require a lot of tables for something that should only be stored for a short while on the device and then transfered by JSON so if possible I would avoid it.

Comment: So why not create a JSON which you save ;)

Comment: That would be nice but the objects have to be editable until the user decides to sync it to the web service, so in that case I have to convert the JSON back to the objects anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add a getter and a setter for your measurements property ? I think you must do it.

Comment: Yes I have those in my real code but they didn't help with the serialization.

Comment: Hum yes, You can't serialize an abstract class because it is not instanciable. Do you your subclasses have ? get/set for each fields, implement serializable and have a default constructor ?

Comment: In fact a serializer will call the default constructor of a class and then use its getters to fill the variables, that's why you need this classes that will be used to serialize.